# Powershell Invoke - RestMethod

Tags: powershell

I would like to use an POST request with powershell but am getting the following errormessage. I have searched many hours, but can't find the problem. The json body seems also to be correct(?).

Thanks in advance for every help!

```
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12' 
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols 
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

    $body = @{
    "client"="myKey"
    "request-type"="authentication"
    "username"="myUsr"
    "password"="myPwd"
    } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

    $header = @{
    "Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    } 


    $res = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://myUrl:4000/abc" -Method 'POST' -Body $body -Headers $header
```

```
Invoke-RestMethod :
Error
Cannot POST /abc
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:8
+ $res = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://myUrl:400 ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

---

Edit:
I have edited my code but get the same error:

```
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12' 
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols 
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

 
$body = @{
"client"="mykey"
"request-type"="authentication"
"username"="myusr"
"password"="mypw"
} 

$res = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://myUrl:4000/abc" -Method 'POST' -Body $body
```

And the 400 error is'nt a error code, I think it's the port.

```
Invoke-RestMethod :
Error
Cannot POST /abc
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:8
+ $res = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://myUrl:400 ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

The request should look like the following:
client=sadsda42424242&request-type=authentication&username=extern&password=geheim

Also I have to use  the content type „application/x-www-form-urlencoded“.

Comment: Please add your code as code, as well as your error message.

Comment: Do you get a 400 error code, or is the 400 in the error message something else?
Do you have some documentation about this website/API on how this call is supposed to work?

Comment: You change the body to become JSON, but you specify the contenttype to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Either [1] set the contenttype to `application/json`, or [2] remove the $header alltogether and do not use ConvertTo-Json on the body hashtable.

Comment: Try using Invoke-WebRequest - this will show you HttpStatusCode, response headers and some other stuff, and as @Theo pointed out you are passing wrong content type in request headers.

Comment: many thanks for your replies. I have edited my question with some more informations.

Comment: @mcbr I am gettng the same error with Invoke-WebRequest:
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot POST /abc
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:8
+ $res = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://myUrl:400 ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : W

Comment: what do you get if you put it in try {....}catch{$_.exception.response.statuscode}

Comment: I think now that it is ja problem of the api. If I am testing it with postman I am getting the message 404 resource not found..